# Daemon stopped syncing

Tags: synchronization, full-node

I am using `v0.14.0.2-release` on Windows, and launching the `monerod` daemon with `./monerod.exe --block-sync-size=10 --data-dir=/f/.monero/` syncs correctly up to height `1788144`. After that, the daemon stops receiving inbound connections and stays stuck there. My current status is

```
Height: 1788144/1797912 (99.5%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 
619.09 MH/s, v10, up to date, 7(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 0m 17s.
```

I've already tried deleting the whole `.monero` folder and sync the whole chain from the beginning, but it seems to get stuck right around there.

I've tried disabling the Windows firewall, the router firewall is enabling inbound connections and I've also tried routing everything through a couple of VPNs (Mullvad and NordVPN) without any change. What else should I try?

Edit: I've also tried deleting p2pstate.bin, with no change.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? What you're describing is usually fixed by killing the daemon, deleting the p2pstate file and relaunching.

Comment: I believe so, yes. I have done that many times over, unfortunately it does not change much, but it's actually syncing at a very slow pace. I'm now on block `1789410` (after 3 hours). I'm probably having bad luck finding other nodes to sync with, but this has been going on for at least one week and I've been able to resync up to 99.5% without issues.

Comment: Couple of things: 1) remove `--block-sync-size=10`, the daemon will use a sane default, 2) ensure there is nothing harming your internet connection speed, 3) you can always check for slow peers by first using the command `print_cn` and then using `ban` for any slow ones.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and report back. My connection is ~50Mbps and is working otherwise fine (I get around 6MB/s with just about everything else), so I'll start banning peers and see what happens!

Comment: Hey, it works! I don't know if it was the block-sync-size (I don't think so?) or me banning a couple of slow peers, but it's now syncing correctly. Answer the question with the `ban` suggestion (which I haven't seen so far as a solution to this kind of problem) so I can mark this as solved!

Comment: Glad it's sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to try in such a situation.

Firstly, remove the argument `--block-sync-size=10`. The daemon uses a sane default, so this option is not required and could potentially cause issues.

Second, try quitting the daemon, deleting `p2pstate.bin`, then restarting the daemon. This clears your previously used peers, which may have been the problem.

Third, you can also check the status of your connected peers with the daemon's `print_cn` command. Look for any particularly slow peers, make a note of their IP addresses, then use the command `ban IP`. This will ban the peer and a new one will be selected from the peer list.